# How can I use iPhone screen hardware as a standard monitor?

Tags: iphone, hardware, screen

I have an old iPhone 4s and I can fully disassemble it. I was searching for a control board to connect the screen and use it as a standard monitor, but I found nothing.
I'm not searching an app or a software to use my phone as a second display, I would rather disconnect the screen from the mother board (which is dead) and use it.

Does anyone know how to connect it to a VGA or HDMI standard input?

Comment: If you use Google Chrome, you can install “Chrome Remote Desktop” which allows you to interact and see your desktop as it is on your PC. Might that help?

Answer (score 1):

The display in the iPhone 4S does not support a standard VGA or HDMI signal as input. This is true both of the iPhone 4S and cell phone displays in general.

Cell phone displays use a very different type of signal - usually MIPI DSI.

Some hobbyist have produced boards that convert HDMI to MIPI DSI which will work with the iPhone 4S screen:

https://hackaday.io/project/364-mipi-dsi-display-shieldhdmi-adapter

However, this is something I guess you would do for the fun of it or for learning. It doesn't make sense in economic terms compared to buying a used monitor.

Comment: Yes, it was for the fun of it, but this is exactly what I’m searching for. Thanks a lot